# Previous Fragment is Loaded on Orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ListView in FragmentTwo(). On clicking the list item i'm directed to FragmentFour() along with the item that I have clicked. When i'm in FragmentFour() when orientation changes, I'm directed back to FragmentTwo().
Why is that?
What other methods do I have to implement?

FragmentTwo

```
public void onBookSelected(String item) {
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentFour();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("book_value",item);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

FragmentFour

```
public static FragmentFour newInstance(Context context) {
    FragmentFour f = new FragmentFour();
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.inflater = inflater;
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onCreateView()",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.book_listview_layout, container, false);
    book = getArguments().getString("book_value");
    setActionBarTitle(book);
    chapter_verse = new ArrayList<String>();
    content = new ArrayList<String>();
    getChapterVerseList();
    getContentList();

    first_load = 0;
    popUpShown = false;

    addItemsToSpinner1(rootView);
    addItemsToSpinner2(rootView);
    addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

    adapter = new BookViewCustomList(this.getActivity(),
            chapter_verse,imageId,content);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewContent);
            String chapter_verse_selected = chapter_verse.get(position);
            if(popUpShown == false) {
                showPopUp(inflater, content.getText().toString(), chapter_verse_selected, book);
                spinner1.setEnabled(false);
                spinner2.setEnabled(false);
                lv.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the code in your Activity which creates `FragmentTwo` in the first place. Maybe you execute this code again in `onCreate()`, replacing the current fragment, if any, with `FragmentTwo`.

Comment: Yes that is the case...Thanks.....any way to stay on FragmentFour retaining the value that was passed from FragmentTwo to FragmentFour ?

Comment: Yes, just check that savedInstanceState is null in `onCreate()` before creating and adding `FragmentTwo`. If it's not, do nothing and the system will restore `FragmentFour`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the constructor of fragment4 instead of calling newinstance.